# Can't understand why string value turns to null suddenly?

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, oncreate

Hers is my code

```
 public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
        private String forecastData;

        private static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        private static final String FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG ="#SunshineApp";

        public DetailFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
            //receive forecast data from the ForeCast Fragment
            Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();
            forecastData=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"data is "+forecastData);
            TextView textView=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text);
            textView.setText(forecastData);

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detailfragment,menu);

            MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
            // Get the provider and hold onto it to set/change the share intent.
            ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider =
                     (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

            // Attach an intent to this ShareActionProvider.  You can update this at any time,
            // like when the user selects a new piece of data they might like to share.
            if (mShareActionProvider!= null ) {
                mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

            }
            else
            {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Share Action Provider is null");
            }
        }
        public  Intent createShareIntent()
        {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"data is "+forecastData);
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,forecastData+DetailFragment.FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"data is "+forecastData);
            return  intent;
        }
```

I am absolutely sure the intent is fired correctly because i can share with other apps and it works ,*It's clear if you see the logs below*

```
01-04 18:36:02.370    6121-6121/com.example.droid.sunshine V/DetailFragment﹕ in optionMenu method data is null
01-04 18:36:02.380    6121-6121/com.example.droid.sunshine V/DetailFragment﹕ in create intent data is null
01-04 18:36:02.380    6121-6121/com.example.droid.sunshine V/DetailFragment﹕ in create intent data is null
01-04 18:36:02.650    6121-6121/com.example.droid.sunshine V/DetailFragment﹕ in view method data is Wed, Jan 7 - Clear - 27/24
```

Why is this , i thought OnCreate() view method was called before OnCreateOptionsMenu()
?what do i do to rectify this?

Comment: EDIT: i moved  `Intent intent=getActivity().getIntent();
            forecastData=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);`      to the `onCreate()` method, still sam results

Comment: **Learn how to use the debugger**.  Trying to build apps without it is like trying to build a house with half of your tools missing.

Comment: ain't logging enough for basic testing?

Comment: No.  If you stepped through this with the debugger, you would find the problem in less time than it took to write this question.  You can inspect the intent and it's extras and determine exactly what is happening.  Logging is for, er, logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea:

- According to your logs, the outputs are FIRST displayed from the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method and only the last one is from the `onCreateView()`. That would mean that `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called before `onCreateView` which would explain why everything is null.
- Try moving `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` somewhere else, maybe in the constructor That should make sure that `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called after `onCreate` and `onCreateView`. Try it.

Comment: No no please read it again , everything is fine , i pass weather data to the DetailActivityFragment , i extract it to a string forecastData(pivate variable of the current ie Fragment class) , when i log it the value is correct as seen in the logs but on logging the same value in 2 other method of the fragment(no static methods as you can see) , the value shown is null

Comment: BTW i didnt pass data here , it was passed as an EXTRA via an intent from  another activity and recieved by this Fragment

Comment: could you do me a favor please and replace `forecastData=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);` with `forecastData=new String(intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));` and let me know if it's still null ?

Comment: Yes still null , I am sure it has nothing to do with android or am i missing something basic here?output is same , except the onCreateView() method where i get the data from intent , elsewhere it is null

Comment: I was thinking that `getStringExtra()` returns a pointer to the `String` object and by the time you get to the `onCreateOptionsMenu` you nullify it somewhere else and that's why.  And with `new String` you were creating a completely new object. But it appears not to have been the case. Hmm ...

Comment: Pointer in java ? btw i do understand string immutablity but i'm pretty SURE THAN CHANGING A INSTANCE FIELD within a method persists afterwards too ...i just wrote a code snippet and checked , can you please help with the problem

Comment: Pointer. Lol. sorry ! I meant it returned the value by reference not by value. :)) I'm currently working in C :D

Comment: Here's a dumb observation, which might explain everything. According to your logs, the outputs are FIRST displayed from the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method and only the last one is from the `onCreateView()`. That would mean that `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called before `onCreateView()` which would explain why everything is null. Move the `getStringExtra()`  inside the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Yeah i did try moving the code to onCreate ,it ran before all else ,still did'nt help , does onCreateOptions run before onCreate() , i guess not!, anyway i'll change and try , please wait

Comment: Before `onCreate` definitely not, but maybe before `onCreateView`, yes, not really sure.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan  In Java, **everything** is passed by value.

Comment: Weird it runs before OnCreate too?, it only works fine when i put the string extract from intent code to the onCreateOptions(), I tried with logs, it is logged before onCreate

Comment: @Simon yeah, true. I got confused there for a second.

Comment: Thanks i found another solution , setHasOptionsMenu(true); ,i moved to to the Fragment constructor , i'm still in the beginning stages of learning the android framework , i'll read the docs further i guess

Answer (score 0):

imho you should move your code from onCreateView() to onActvivityCreated().

onCreateView is meant to return the view.

onActivityCreated means that the associated activity has completed its method onCreate() and is set up.